# How can i get xdebug to work inside Docker on remote server

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, phpstorm, xdebug

So, I spent about two days and can't make `xdebug` work in the container (docker-compose config) on the remote server

And I always get `E: Time-out connecting to the client. :-(`

#### Dev machine:

- Win10 with dynamic IP
- All the code is real-time syncing with remote server (via "deployment" feature)
- PhpStorm is configured to listen on port 9001, "Listen for PHP Debug Connections" is on.
- No servers and etc, just zero-config debugging session.

#### Remote server:

xdebug config:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_log="/var/www/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

php-fpm, jwilder/nginx-proxy, letsencrypt-companion, nginx, jeroenpeeters/docker-ssh running via docker-compose.

Here is a simplified version of docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy

services:

  nginx-proxy:
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
    volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    - ./secured/certs_letsencrypt:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
    - /etc/nginx/vhost.d
    - /usr/share/nginx/html
    restart: always

  letsencrypt-companion:
    container_name: letsencrypt-companion
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    volumes:
    - ./secured/certs_letsencrypt:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    volumes_from:
    - nginx-proxy
    restart: always

  my_project_nginx:
    container_name: my_project_nginx
    build:
      context: ./containers/nginx_ssl
      args:
        appcontainer: my_project_app
        domain: example.com
    depends_on:
    - nginx-proxy
    links:
    - my_project_app
    - nginx-proxy
    environment:
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=example.com
    - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=example.com
    - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=stepan@example.com
    restart: always

  my_project_app:
    container_name: my_project_app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./containers/php7_1/Dockerfile
      args:
        idrsafile: ./secured/id_rsa_shared
        php_memory_limit: 6G
    depends_on:
    - nginx-proxy
    restart: always

  my_project_ssh:
    container_name: my_project_ssh
    image: jeroenpeeters/docker-ssh
    depends_on:
    - my_project_app
    volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - ./secured/authorized_keys:/authorized_keys
    ports:
    - "2227:22"
    environment:
    - FILTERS={"name":["my_project_app"]}
    - AUTH_MECHANISM=publicKey
    - AUTHORIZED_KEYS=/authorized_keys
    restart: always
```

#### The problem

And there is `xdebug` log:

```
... 
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 5.18.238.83:9001.
E: Time-out connecting to the client. :-(
```

I tried a lot of variants (specified xdebug.remote_host, established SSH tunnel via Putty etc) and still got no results.

Comment: Did you check your firewall log?

Comment: @FabianH. are you talking about docker host firewall log?

Comment: Check firewall (Windows, Docker, Linux) + IP address correctness. Is `5.18.238.83` the actual IP? Maybe try `docker.internal.host` for `xdebug.remote_host` and disable `connect_back`.

Comment: All of them, but mainly your local system where the connection should come in.  Instead of the SSH tunnel, you could also configure your router to forward the incoming connection to your computer (NAT). If it works, the reverse connection through your SSH tunnel was blocked/not enabled.

Comment: How did you configure your tunnel, did you follow the PhpStorm manual? https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Remote+debugging+in+PhpStorm+via+SSH+tunnel

Comment: @LazyOne yes, `5.18.238.83` is my actual IP. If i specify `xdebug.remote_host = docker.internal.host` then xdebug client will try to connect to Docker host, not my dev machine with running IDE, right? How will this work?

Comment: @FabianH. right, i did it acording to this manual. But i use `jeroenpeeters/docker-ssh` to ssh into php container because there is no ssh server running in docker container. And i dont know how to commute 9001 port in `my_project_app` container with this `my_project_ssh` container

Comment: i use docker-machine with a VM, and the ip is `192.168.99.100`, give that a try. I can't get it to connect when i try and do it natively however, xdebug only seemed to work when i was using a docker-machine as the base vm. Here's my entire setup https://github.com/delboy1978uk/lamp

Comment: By using a tunnel, xdebug needs to connect to the server's ssh service instead of the requesting client IP. As LazyOne suggested, you should disable  `xdebug.connect_back` and set `xdebug.remote_host`

Comment: @FabianH. @LazyOne, looks i cant use `docker.internal.host` because i have networks: external. Port 9001 is open on remote server...